# Test with Espresso and mocked dataSource fails

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I have a button in my app and when user clicks i, it displays a Text. Now I want to test it with `Espresso`.

The code in `MainActivity` is :

```
public void onButtonGetDataClick(View view) {
    mainPresenter.onButtonClick();
}

@Override
public void showData(String data) {
    textView.setText(data);
}
```

and for `mainPresenter.onButtonClick()` :

```
    @Override
public void onButtonClick() {
    if (dataSource != null) {
        mainView.showData(dataSource.getReleaseString());
    }
}
```

where `dataSource` is injected to `MainPresenter`.

The problem is how I can test such a thing ? I tried mocking `dataSource` and test it like :

```
    @Test
public void onButtonGetDataClicked_textViewDisplaysData() {
    when(dataSource.getReleaseString()).thenReturn(MOCK_STRING);

    activityRule.launchActivity(new Intent());

    /** Click Button*/
    onView(withId(R.id.btn_get_data))
            .perform(click());

    onView(withId(R.id.tv_text_data))
            .check(matches(withText(MOCK_STRING)));

}
```

but this is always giving me the "RELEASE_STRING" and not "MOCK_STRING" therefore test always fails

Edit : injection code :

```
    @Before
public void setUp() {

    mockMainView = mock(MainMVP.View.class);
    mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(mockMainView);

    Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
    MockMyApplication applicationContext
            = (MockMyApplication) instrumentation.getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
    MockDataComponent component = (MockDataComponent) applicationContext.component();
    component.inject(mainPresenter);

}
```

and of course I use

```
@Inject
DataSource dataSource;
```

MockDataComponent :

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {MockDataModule.class})
public interface MockDataComponent extends DemoComponent {

void inject(MainPresenter mainPresenter);

}
```

and MockDataModule :

```
@Module
public class MockDataModule {

@Provides
public DataSource providesDataSource() {
    return mock(DataSource.class);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post the injection code of datasource? Are you using Dagger for dependency injection?

Comment: What about the module of MockDataComponent?

Comment: @Niko added also `MockDataComponent` and `MockDataModule`.

Comment: Have you debugged the code that providesDataSource from your MockDataModule gets called?

Comment: @Niko you mean this code :  `@Override
  public DataSource get() {
    return Preconditions.checkNotNull(
        module.providesDataSource(), "Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method");
  }`
from `MockDataModule_ProvidesDataSourceFactory` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124781/discussion-between-niko-and-mes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the presenter for your `Activity` here so the mock datasource cannot be accessed.

By making Presenter component allows you to inject presenter for your activity and this singleton presenter can then have the mock datasource to present.